# From csv to txt

Tags: r, csv, text

How can i convert a csv file to a plain text file?

My CSV file consists of 3 columns and i only want to get the values of the column "Text" in the text file. I tried to achieve this with the following:

```
name <- read.csv('c:/Users/bi2/Documents/TextminingRfiles/ScoreOutput/RangersScores.csv', header=T, sep=",")
attach(name)
posText <- name[score > 0,]> name <- read.csv('c:/Users/bi2/Documents/TextminingRfiles/ScoreOutput/RangersScores.csv', header=T, sep=",")
attach(name)
posText <- name[score > 0,]
write(posText$text, file = "C:/Users/bi2/Documents/TextminingRfiles/ScoreOutput/namePositive.txt", sep="")
```

This code only copies the indexes to the text file, but not the text values of the text column. How can i fix this?

Tnx for your help.

Comment: What is content of `posText$text` ? That should give you a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few extra arguments to `write.table` will probably get what you want.

Here's a reproducible example, make a CSV with three columns...

```
write.csv(data.frame(x = sample(26),
                     y = sample(26),
                     text = letters),
          file = "test.csv")
```

Now read it into `R`...

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv")
```

Now do your other calculations, then subset to get only the column you want to write to a txt file...

```
test <- test[ ,which(names(test) == 'text')]
```

And now write it to a txt file, with no row names, column names or quote marks...

```
write.table(test, "test.txt", 
            row.names = FALSE, 
            quote = FALSE, 
            col.names = FALSE)
```

By the way, the `attach`ing in the code in your question is unnecessary and not recommended.